# Issue on Merging Two Functions in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can you please help me to clean [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Proweb/85nvn/1/) code as

Ideally , I would like to generate a function `validateEmail()` with a parameter `(email)` and just call the function on form submission , some thing like this

```
function validateEmail(email){
  // code
}

// Call function on form submission
$('#myform').submit(function() {
   validateEmail($("#txtEmail").val());
})
```

right now I have this code , which is working fine for me but it keeps the `.submit()` function too messy and I need to make the function more reusable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
function ValidateEmail(email) {
        var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
        return expr.test(email);
    };

$('#myform').submit(function() {
var abort = false;  
        if (!ValidateEmail($("#txtEmail").val())) {
            $(this).parent().after('<div class="err"> Valid Email Adress Requierd</div>');
            abort = true;
        }
     if (abort) { return false; } else { return true; }
    })//on submit
}); // ready
```

[Here is a working example of the Form](http://jsfiddle.net/Proweb/85nvn/1/)

Comment: It is unclear what problem you're trying to solve.  Form validate belongs in the submit method.  If you have multiple validation checks, you put each of them in the submit method, one after the other.

Comment: that is exavtly what I do not want to do! I want to keep validators in diffrent functions and just simply call them in .submit()

Comment: [Don't reinvent the wheel](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation).

Comment: Thanks Mooon Wave but I really need to learn this.

Comment: @Behseini - yeah, that's what I mean.  Call each validation function from the submit function.  So what is your question?

Comment: well I do not know how to generate the function()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    function ValidateEmail(obj, email) {
        var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
        var testedEmail = expr.test(email);

        var abort = false;  
        if (!testedEmail) {
            $(obj).parent().after('<div class="err"> Valid Email Adress Requierd</div>');
            abort = true;
        }

            if (abort) { return false; } else { return true; }    
    } 

    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        return ValidateEmail(this, $("#txtEmail").val())
    });

}); // ready
```

Here [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Proweb/85nvn/1/).

Comment: thanks mucio, this exactly what I was looking for the only point is can you please let me know what is obj and why did you use it?

Comment: obj is the first parameter of ValidateEmail and I used it to pass a refence to #myform that is calling it and passing itself (this). I'm not a js expert so maybe the standard way to call the dom object that is calling a function is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var __REGEXINT__ = '__REGEXINT__',

var __REGEXCEP__ = '__REGEXCEP__';

var __REGEXMAIL__ = '__REGEXMAIL__';

var validator = {

    _targetErrors : '#sectionErrors',

    setError: function(msg){

        var message = '<p>{message}</p>'.replace('{message}', msg);

        $(this._targetErrors).append(message)
    },

    __renderInputs : function(__inputs__){


        function __getValueOfTarget(target, delimitator){

            if(!target)
                return false;

            if(typeof target == "string")

                return $(target).val();

            else if(typeof target == "object"){

                var _return_ = [];

                if(!delimitator)
                    delimitator = '';

                for(var id in target)
                    _return_.push(__getValueOfTarget(target[id]));


                return _return_.join(delimitator);
            }

            return false;
        }

        var __return__ = {};
        var __error__ = false;

        for(name in __inputs__){

            var input = __inputs__[name];
            var value = __return__[name] = __getValueOfTarget(input.target, input.delimitator);
            var foundError = false;
            if(!input.validator){

                __return__[name] = value;
                continue;

            } else {

                for(var validatorID in input.validator){

                    if(foundError)
                        continue;

                    switch(input.validator[validatorID]){

                        case 'empty':
                            if(value == ""){
                                __error__ = foundError = true;
                                this.setError(input.validator_error[ validatorID ]);
                                continue;
                            }
                        break;

                        case __REGEXINT__:
                            if(!/^(\d+)$/.test(value)){
                                __error__ = foundError = true; 
                                this.setError(input.validator_error[ validatorID ]);
                                continue;
                            }
                        break;

                        case __REGEXCEP__:
                            if(!/^(\d{5}\-\d{3})$/.test(value)){
                                __error__ = foundError = true; 
                                this.setError(input.validator_error[ validatorID ]);
                                continue;
                            }
                        break;

                        case __REGEXCEP__:
                            if(!/^(\d{5}\-\d{3})$/.test(value)){
                                __error__ = foundError = true; 
                                this.setError(input.validator_error[ validatorID ]);
                                continue;
                            }
                        break;

                        case __REGEXMAIL__:
                            if(!/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/.test(value)){
                                __error__ = foundError = true; 
                                this.setError(input.validator_error[ validatorID ]);
                                continue;
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (__error__) ? false : __return__
    }
}

var __inputs__ = {

    id:{
        target:"#id_terminal",
        validator:["empty", __REGEXINT__ ],
        validator_error:[
            "Por favor insira a ID do terminal.",
            "Por favor insira uma ID valida."
        ]
    },

    name:{
        target:"#name",
        validator:["empty"],
        validator_error:["Por favor insira o nome do estabelecimento."]
    },

    uf:{
        target:"#uf",
        validator:["empty"],
        validator_error:["Por favor insira o estado."]
    },

    mail:{
        target:"#mail",
        validator:["empty", __REGEXMAIL__],
        validator_error:["Por favor insira um e-mail.", "Por favor insira um e-mail valido"]
    },

    cep:{
        target:[".cep", ".cep2"],
        delimitator:'-',
        validator:["empty", __REGEXCEP__ ],
        validator_error:[
            "Por favor insira o cep.",
            "Por favor insira um cep valido."
        ]
    }
}

$('#myform').submit(function() {
    if(!validator.__renderInputs(__inputs__))
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Hi Guilherme , Thanks for you comment but this exactly opposite way! I was thinking to keep everything out of the submit function since I am going to add more validation rules there!

Comment: kk okay i think in other method to help you. I think that i have the code to this..

Comment: Please check my updates how this you can use multiple validators. Sorry for messages error in portuguese..